# defmacro to generate another defmacro

Tags: clojure, macros

I have run into this problem... I have two macros that look very similar

```
(import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory)

(defmacro with-thread-manager [tm & body]
  {:pre [(and (vector? tm) (= 1 (count tm)))]}
  `(let [~(first tm) (ManagementFactory/getThreadMXBean)]
     ~@body))

(defmacro with-os-manager [tm & body]
  {:pre [(and (vector? tm) (= 1 (count tm)))]}
  `(let [~(first tm) (ManagementFactory/getOperatingSystemMXBean)]
     ~@body))
```

they are used as follows:

```
(defn thread-count []
  (with-thread-manager [tm] (.getThreadCount tm)))

(thread-count)
;; => 12

(defn application-cpu-time []
  (with-os-manager [osm] (.getProcessCpuTime osm)))

(application-cpu-time)
;; => 71260000000
```

I wish to generalise the two `with-*-manager` into another macro so that I can simpify them like this:

```
(defmanagementblock with-thread-manager (ManagementFactory/getThreadMXBean))
(defmanagementblock with-os-manager (ManagementFactory/getOperatingSystemMXBean))
```

---

so the easiest way I knew was to change the macro a little bit

```
(defmacro with-thread-manager [tm & body]
  {:pre [(and (vector? tm) (= 1 (count tm)))]}
  (apply list 'let [(first tm) '(ManagementFactory/getThreadMXBean)]
      body))
```

and to write the block:

```
(defmacro defmanageblock [name MANAGER]
  (list 'defmacro name '[tm & body]
    '{:pre [(and (vector? tm) (= 1 (count tm)))]}
    (list 'apply 'list ''let (vector '(first tm) 'MANAGER)
          'body)))
```

everything goes well except the MANAGER does not quote properly. I've tried a bunch of quoting and unquoting option like `'` , ` , `~'` and many other variations of it. but it does not give the right value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reasonable solution, if you don't mind keeping track of a few scopes in your head:

```
(defmacro defmanagedblock [name mgr]
  `(defmacro ~name [tm# & body#]
     {:pre [(and (vector? tm#)) (= 1 (count tm#))]}
     `(let [~(first tm#) ~'~mgr]
        ~@body#)))
```

Comment: oh you rock! that did the trick. how does \` and ' work in the case of the line  `\`(let [~(first tm#) ~'~mgr]...)`  ?

Answer (score 5):

If you define defmanageblock to be a function that takes a symbol describing the factory to use which returns the s-expression as a list then you would have **two macros that call functions instead of nested macros** . In most cases doing the real code generation work in functions rather than macros makes the code easier to reason about and test